# "try and be more assertive" VS "try to be more assertive"

Tags: difference, to-infinitive

I am not a native English speaker but I am very used to using **try to be more + (Adjective)** form.

But very often do I get to see native English speakers use **try and be more (Adjective)** form.

I'd like to know if there is any difference between the two structures.
For example, is there any difference between the sentence 1 and the sentence 2 below?

> Sentence 1: You should try and be more assertive.
>
> Sentence 2: You should try to be more assertive.

Thank you for your help as always.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it okay to use the phrase "try and"? Is it grammatically correct? e.g. "I will try and answer".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119151/is-it-okay-to-use-the-phrase-try-and-is-it-grammatically-correct-e-g-i-wil) See [this gem of a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27008/why-do-we-say-try-and-do-something-instead-of-try-to-do-it#comment46633_27024) by Peter Shor over on ELU. And ignore any pedants who tell you ***and*** is "incorrect".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wow, there was one already. I actually searched with certain keywords before asking and I couldn't find that thread.

Comment: The earlier **ELL** question cited as a dup isn't as good as that one I linked to through that comment on **ELU**. Not that I'm singing the praises of my own answer there (it's got *way* less upvotes than the top answer), but that brilliant comment from Peter Shor was so neat that I've always remembered it. (I actually feel quite proud of having edited it into my answer, though I freely admit I'm incapable of coming up with such a concise juxtaposition all by myself! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Wow, it looks like a pretty neat and delicate answer and comments so I think I need some time to digest it. Actually it is a rare honor to get to see a great answer like that by being notified by the very writer of the answer. Thank you for the link, and I will read word by word through it.

Comment: Those mean exactly the same thing and the difference is merely **stylistic**.