# Try and/to do something

Tags: catenative-verbs

Page 54 of A Practical English Grammar reads

> We often use and... instead of *to* after *try / be sure*. This is
> informal. *I'll **try** and phone you tomorrow morning.*

However, in page 299, it reads

> To talk about making an experiment - doing something to see what will
> happen - we use *try* + -ing.

Aren't both statements at odds?[image]

*Try and* cannot come from *try to* in *I'll try and phone you tomorrow morning* since, as the picture from the book that's what you mean shows, *try* followed by infinitive to implies an effort to do something (at least in the present tense used in those examples), unlike [*try* + -ing](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/try_1?q=try),

Comment: Does this answer your question? [try+gerund/infinitive (Difference in meaning)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44160/trygerund-infinitive-difference-in-meaning) Also [try + gerund/infinitive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124463/try-gerund-infinitive) (same title, but a separate question).

Comment: Darn it, I meant to use this question as the duplicate target but accidentally hit return: [Is it okay to use the phrase “try and”? Is it grammatically correct? e.g. “I will try and answer …”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/119151/9161) It more explicitly talks about "try and".

Answer (score 1):

In many contexts you will find them used interchangeably. The difference in meaning is usually negligible, but in certain contexts it can be discerned.

- If you *try to do* something, you directly attempt it.
- If you *try and do* something, you attempt to find the time or means to do it.

For example, if someone asked me to attend an event and I said "I will try *and* get there", it would be an indication that I will attempt to be present. Saying "I will try *to get* there" would sound like I wasn't sure if I could complete the journey. However, if I used the verb *to be* and said "I will try *to be* there", this removes the journey element and makes it a binary choice - either I will be there, or I won't - and in this context the difference is not really discernable.

"I will try to call you" *could* mean you would attempt to make the call, dial the number etc; whereas "I will try and call you" would mean you will try to find the time or the means to call them. This is consistent with the image you posted captioned "try *to* call", as it depicts a man reaching for the telephone *to* make a call.

Comment: I think this is a spurious distinction. Strictly speaking, only ***try to*** is "correct", leading to the ["Try **and** convict me!""](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124463/try-gerund-infinitive#comment251353_124463) wordplay.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Don't just *think* it is spurious - please be sure if you are going to downvote! The example you cite only proves my point. The quotation "try *and* convict me" is baiting someone to *find the means* with which to convict, not to actually begin proceedings (which ought not to be possible without evidence anyway).

Comment: One finds Verb and Verb all over the place in English, and it is the same exact thing as Verb to Verb. So, they can each mean something different, or the speaker might mean the same thing using either.

Comment: @Lambie Agreed, this is the point I made in my opening words. But other times, there could be a perceived difference.